# How do I use _com_ptr_t with RenderTargetView and DepthStencilView?

Tags: directx11

I have successfully used `_com_ptr_t` with the `ID3D11Device` and `IDXGISwapChain` but when applying the same reasoning to the `RenderTargetView` and `DepthStencilView`, the function `m_spD3DImmediateContext->OMSetRenderTargets(...)` sets the `m_spRenderTargetView` smart COM pointer to null! Then, subsequent draw calls fail on `ClearRenderTargetView` and `ClearDepthStencilView`.

Is it because I am passing the smart pointer incorrectly?

```
HR(m_spD3DDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(pBackBuffer, 0, &m_spRenderTargetView));
...
HR(m_spD3DDevice->CreateTexture2D(&stDepthStencilDesc, 0, &m_spDepthStencilBuffer));
...
m_spD3DImmediateContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &m_spRenderTargetView, m_spDepthStencilView);
assert(m_spRenderTargetView); // <=== FAIL
```

I think the smart pointer overloads the `operator&` so that it returns an `Interface**` (see Extractors in [`_com_ptr_t` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/417w8b3b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are hitting is that `OMSetRenderTargets` does not take a pointer to the RenderTargetView object. It takes a pointer to an array of pointers to RenderTargetView objects to support Multiple Render Target (MRT) rendering configurations.

```
void OMSetRenderTargets(UINT NumViews, ID3D11RenderTargetView *const *ppRenderTargetViews,
    ID3D11DepthStencilView *pDepthStencilView );
```

The default operator& overload for _com_ptr_t and Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr assume you are using the pattern like in `CreateRenderTarget` so it Releases the object and sets the pointer to null before returning the address of the contained pointer. This avoids a leak. Note the older ATL CComPtr's operator& did not Release and instead asserted the pointer to be null.

```
HR(m_spD3DDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(pBackBuffer, 0, &m_spRenderTargetView));
```

With Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr, you can use the explicit `GetAddressOf()` or `ReleaseAndGetAddressOf()` methods to get the 'right' behavior. This is why generally ComPtr (or the older ATL CComPtr) is preferred to _com_ptr_t for Direct3D programming.

```
HR(m_spD3DDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(pBackBuffer, 0, m_spRenderTargetView.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf()));
...
HR(m_spD3DDevice->CreateTexture2D(&stDepthStencilDesc, 0, m_spDepthStencilBuffer.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf()));
...
m_spD3DImmediateContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, m_spRenderTargetView.GetAddressOf(), m_spDepthStencilView);
```

With _com_ptr_t you need to use something like:

```
ID3D11RenderTargetView* rtv = m_spRenderTargetView.GetInterfacePtr();
m_spD3DImmediateContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &rtv, m_spDepthStencilView);
```

Comment: In addition here are some links [Smart COM Pointers (Modern C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh279674.aspx)" and [Wiki ATL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Template_Library) You mentioned Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr but I dont know how to include the neccassary headers to instantiate this. I downloaded the _WRL Class Library_ extension to VS2012 but I still can't '#include <WRL\*anything*>'

Comment: With VS 2012 or VS 2013 you just use ``#include <wrl/client.h>``. For VS 2010, you can use the Windows 8.x SDK with the integration [instructions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/11/23/using-the-windows-8-sdk-with-visual-studio-2010-configuring-multiple-projects.aspx). Those instructions omit the 'include\winrt' path unfortunately which you need for ``Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr``. You can get working .props files from my blog for the [Windows 8.1 SDK](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/10/18/visual-studio-2013-and-windows-8-1-sdk-rtm-are-now-available.aspx).

Comment: Note that ``Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr`` works fine in Windows Store apps, Windows Phone apps, Win32 desktop apps for Windows Vista or later, and Xbox One apps. I use it extensively in [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929).

Comment: I've got it. It was the fact that I was using DirectXSDK directory and not the Windows Kits 8.0 directory.